# Validate Div tag separately

Tags: asp.net, javascript, vb.net

I have 3 div tags. Each having no. of textboxes and button. Each textbox having validation. For all button causesvalidation property is true. If I click "button1" in "div1" tag will cause validation of other textbox in other div tags. I don't want to do this. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the ValidationGroup property of the elements in each div to a separate validation group.

Example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Div1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="Div1"></asp:Button>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="Textbox1" ValidationGroup="Div1" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Div2"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="Div2"></asp:Button>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="Textbox2" ValidationGroup="Div2" ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Div3"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="Div3"></asp:Button>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="Textbox3" ValidationGroup="Div3" ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Validation Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx).